# Where to place InvokeRepeating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Hero : MonoBehaviour {
    float speed = 2f;
    bool hero_up = false;
    bool hero_down = false;
    bool hero_left = false;
    bool hero_right = false;
    public Animator animator;
    public Rigidbody2D rbEnemy;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        EnemySpawn ();
    }

    void EnemySpawn()
    {
        Rigidbody2D EnemyInstance;
        EnemyInstance = Instantiate(rbEnemy, new Vector3(Random.Range (2f, 8f), Random.Range (-4f, 4f) ,0f), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f,0f,0f))) as Rigidbody2D;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    InvokeRepeating("EnemySpawn", 3, 3);
}
```

I receive the following message error:

> error CS1519: Unexpected symbol `EnemySpawn' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Public variables (Animator and Rigidbody2d) are correctly set

Where should move InvokeRepeating ? I searched some answers; I moved InvokeRepeating in Start and  at the the end of the EnemySpawn. The results was that an increasing number of enemy for each frame.
What is the solution of this problem ?

Comment: where is `InvokeRepeating` actually called? it doesn't look like its in a method.

Comment: put it inside `Start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Hero : MonoBehaviour {
    float speed = 2f;
    bool hero_up = false;
    bool hero_down = false;
    bool hero_left = false;
    bool hero_right = false;
    public Animator animator;
    public Rigidbody2D rbEnemy;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();

    // Invokes the method methodName in time seconds, then repeatedly every   repeatRate seconds.
    InvokeRepeating("EnemySpawn", 3, 3);

    }

    void EnemySpawn()
    {
        Rigidbody2D EnemyInstance;
        EnemyInstance = Instantiate(rbEnemy, new Vector3(Random.Range (2f, 8f), Random.Range (-4f, 4f) ,0f), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f,0f,0f))) as Rigidbody2D;

    }

}
```

As u said it so much increasing the enemy spawn then, use large repeatedRate i.e., third argument of InvokeRepeating method.

If you do InvokeRepeating("Function", 1.0f, 1.0f), it will call Function one second after the InvokeRepeating call and then every one second thereafter